# isolate the number exists at the end of the URI php

Tags: php, regex

I have the following URI:

```
  /belt/belts/fk/product/40P35871
```

And I want to retrieve the last content after the last /.
In this case is 40P35871.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regex for something simple like that. Consider using `strrchr`, documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php)

```
$lastcontent = substr(strrchr($uri, "/"), 1);
```

Considering this special case of $uri being a path, the best answer would be the one provided by Chtulhu.

`basename` will return the last part of a path, documentation [here](https://www.php.net/basename)

```
$lastcontent = basename($uri);
```

Comment: not that I begrudge you the 15 rep, but @NickRobertson, I'd go for accepting Cthulhu's answer, to show future visitors of the question the simplest solution.

Comment: I will update the answer, in case the accepted solution doesn't change

Answer (score 5):

How about [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

```
$elements = explode('/', $input);
$productId = end($elements);
```

Comment: if he's only interested in the last part, is there a reason to construct an array to hold all the other segments too? what would be the advantage of using this method versus `strrchr`?

Comment: @emartel I don't know. Readability? Simplicity? It's really just an alternative approach. If this line of code becomes the bottleneck in his application, you could surely profile all answers to this question and pick the fastest one ;)

Comment: oh, sorry, that was a legitimate question, not trying to make my solution look better, I'm not a PHP guy.

Comment: @emartel I didn't want to seem defensive. This was also just the best answer I could come up with. It was the first solution that popped to my mind, and you are right it might be less efficient than using `strrchr`. But without profiling it, I wouldn't make any claims. And I guess this approach is more easily extensible to getting other elements of the path as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Here's a different solution entirely.**  (and the simplest!)

Using **[`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)**

```
$var = "/belt/belts/fk/product/40P35871";
echo basename($var);
```

**Output:**

```
40P35871
```

Comment: That's a very handy to know! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Just like this

```
$str = '/belt/belts/fk/product/40P35871';
$arr = explode('/', $str);
$var = array_pop($arr);
var_dump($var);
```

or

```
$var = substr($str, strrpos($str,'/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
$result = preg_replace('%(/(?:[^/]+?/)+)([^/]+)\b%', '$2', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
echo preg_replace('/[a-z0-9]$/i', '$1', $url);
```

this will give you the last position

note: but on this url only, query strings make this useless and use need to parse the url for the same first for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex. In this case you can act as the follow

```
myUrl = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URL];
$number = substr(strrpos(myUri,'/')+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You don't need `regex`.

Find the last content and get it using `substr()`:

```
$lastcontent = substr(strrchr($uri, "/"), 1);
```